# How do I get my code to run the if statement?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python and I'm writing a code for a school project and ran into an early bug.
For some reason my if function won't run.

```
import time            #imports computer time to program(buit in function)
count= 0

print("                                           Gymship")  # center this
print("--------------------------------------")  # this should go across the whole screen
print("Input a level to view the description or InputSign up to begin signing up for a card")
print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("Bronze")
time.sleep(1)  # this wil pause the program for 1 second(for effect)
 print("Silver")
time.sleep(1)
print("Gold")
time.sleep(1)
print("Platinum")
time.sleep(2)
print("-----------------------------------------------")  # this should go across the whole screen
print("Sign up")
print(" ")
input()
if input == "Bronze":
    print("Bronze")
    print("--------------------------------------------")
    print("You acquire a bronze card when you use two or less gym services")
    print("2 Hours limit in  the gym")
    print("-------------------------------------")
    print(input("Back to return to menu screen"))



count = count + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct:

```
input()
if input == "Bronze":
```

The way `input()` works is by *returning* a value. The name `input` refers to the function itself, so the function `input` will never equal the text `"Bronze"` unless you explicitly do something bad, like `input = "Bronze"` (it's bad because if you overwrite `input`, you'll no longer be able to access that function).

Instead, you should be using the returned value:

```
usr_input = input()
if usr_input == "Bronze":
```

Also, the line `print(input("Back to return to menu screen"))` is unnecessarily complicated; the `print()` will print whatever was returned by `input()`, but `input()` will display the `"Back to return to menu screen"` prompt without wrapping it in an `if` statement. So, `input("Back to return to menu screen")` is all you need. If you keep it the way you have it, if someone typed some text and then hit enter, the text would display again, because the `print()` is printing whatever that text was that the user typed.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to assign a variable to the input and then check if the variable is equal to "Bronze"
Right now you are taking the input, but are not storing it anywhere. So the fixed code would be

```
user_input = input()
if user_input == "Bronze":
```